Source generator partial method not being called
I am trying out writing a source generator following this guide, however my method implementation isn't being called.
My source generator looks like:
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

namespace SourceGenerator.Example
{

    [Generator]
    public class HelloSourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            var mainMethod = context.Compilation.GetEntryPoint(context.CancellationToken);

            // Build up the source code
            string source = $@"// <auto-generated/>
using System;

namespace {mainMethod.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString()}
{{
    public partial class {mainMethod.ContainingType.Name}
    {{
        partial void HelloFrom(string name) {{
            //Console.WriteLine($""Generator says: Hi from '{{name}}'"");
            throw new Exception (""wat"");
        }}
    }}
}}
";
            var typeName = mainMethod.ContainingType.Name;

            // Add the source code to the compilation
            context.AddSource($"{typeName}.g.cs", source);
        }

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            // No initialization required for this one
        }
    }
}

I also have a console app that references the source generator project, that looks like:
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before source generator");
            var app = new Program();
            app.HelloFrom("test");
            Console.WriteLine("After source generator");
        } 
        
        partial void HelloFrom(string name);
    }
}

They are in separate projects. I am referencing the source generator correctly, and I can see the following generated code in my console project:
using System;

namespace Example
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        partial void HelloFrom(string name) {
            //Console.WriteLine($"Generator says: Hi from '{name}'");
            throw new Exception ("wat");
        }
    }
}

However the output of my console app is
Before source generator
After source generator

If I debug the project, it just skips over HelloFrom.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
